# Malloc Memory Leaks "Allocated Prior To Attach"

Tags: swift, xcode, profiling, instruments, google-maps-sdk-ios

[SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y0T3.png)
[Xcode debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20W1h.png)

I've isolated the issue to the point where the entire app consists of just this single View Controller still getting same 36 leaks

Google Maps SDK Version: 8.1.0
Xcode Version: 14.3
Device/Emulator: iOS 16.6

I have 2 same projects 1 is without any leaks.
Kindly someone point me toword right direction trying to find leaks since last week

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you think this is a bug in the Maps SDK itself, feel free to file a bug in the Google Public issue tracker: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker